# posiciones y listas paralelas en python

Tags: python

Listas paralelas y posicionamiento
Tengo un problema con Python. Necesito poner una cantidad a una posición en concreto en 3 listas que son paralelas, pero no se acceder a esa posición dependiendo del nombre que hay en la primera lista. Tengo 3 listas paralelas, la primera lista ingreso unos artículos, en la segunda lista un precio de el artículo correspondiente a la posición de la lista anterior y en la tercera lista necesito poner en la misma posición correspondiente al artículo.

```
#por ejemplo: 
articulos = []
precioArt = []
c_articulos_vendidos = []
articulos = input("ingresar un artículo")
precioArt = input("ingresar un precio")

'''
Aquí todo bien porque al ingresar un valor a cada lista comparten la misma posición, pero cuando quiero añadir una cantidad a un artículo en especifico, necesito asignar ese valor a la misma posición que ese artículo. Todas estas entradas son por teclado.
'''
#Ahora para poner esa cantidad en la misma posición hago esto:



nombre_articulo = input("Nombre del artículo que has vendido:")
        for i in range(len(articulos)):
            if nombre_articulo in articulos:
                c_articulos_vendidos = int(input("Cuantos has vendido?"))
                print(c_articulos_vendidos)
        else:
            print("El artículo", nombre_articulo,"no existe")
```

Comment: Lo que quieres es posible hacer con tres listas "paralelas", como les llamas. Sin embargo, lo que necesitas es hacer uso de la estructura de dato correcta. En este caso, es un diccionario cuyas keys sean los nombres de los artículos, y los valores pueden ser diccionarios que tengan la información adicional.

Comment: La cosa es que tengo que hacerlo con 3 listas paralelas, no puedo utilizar ni tuplas ni diccionarios.

Comment: Tengo que recorrer la lista de articulos y poner en la misma posición esa cantidad.

Answer (score 0):

Si solo lo podes hacer con listas, una solución podría ser

```
c_articulos_vendidos = [0]*len(articulos)
nombre_articulo = input("Nombre del artículo que has vendido:")
if nombre_articulo in articulos:
    i = articulos.index(nombre_articulo)
    c_articulos_vendidos[i] = int(input("Cuantos has vendido?"))
    print(c_articulos_vendidos)
else:
    print("El artículo", nombre_articulo,"no existe")
```

Con `c_articulos_vendidos = [0]*len(articulos)` inicializo la lista con la cantidad de elementos que tiene articulos, para poder asignarle la cantidad dentro del `if`. Luego pregunto si el articulo que se vendió está dentro de articulos, si está busco el [index](https://docs.python.org/es/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) del articulo para luego usarlo en la asignación de la cantidad vendida.

Otra solución, en lugar de usar `articulos.index(nombre_articulo)` podría ser usando `enumerate()`:

```
for index, articulo in enumerate(articulos):
    if articulo == articulo_vendido:
        print(index)
```

La diferencia en estas dos soluciones es que usando `enumerate()` te devuelve los index de todas las posiciones en la que se repita la palabra dentro de la lista, pero en tu caso no necesitas esto.

Además el método `index()` es más rápido que `enumerate()`

```
>>> python -m timeit "['foo', 'bar', 'baz'].index('bar')"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.147 usec per loop
>>>python -m timeit "[i for i, j in enumerate(['foo', 'bar', 'baz']) if j == 'bar']"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.402 usec per loop
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Voy a probarlo.